# Inappropriate ioctl for device at when calling unoconv from perl script

Tags: perl, postfix-mta, document-conversion

I'm triggering a perl script from an postfix email server every time when an email is received for a specified domain. The perl script basically extracts all attachments and then calls unoconv to convert the attachments to PDF format.

I'm currently testing the script with always the same email with the same attachments and I see a random behavior. Sometimes all attachments get converted, sometime I get the error "Inappropriate ioctl for device at" ERROR when calling the unoconv command like:

```
unoconv -f pdf -o /tmp/2151DC80-A545-11E4-880B-D7DC6512523E/ '/tmp/2151DC80-A545-11E4-880B-D7DC6512523E/attachments/21887524-A545-11E4-880B-D7DC6512523E-test.doc'
```

Looks like some racing condition issue or similar. What can be the problem?

UPDATE: The problem seems se be that unoconv sometimes exits with a Floating point exception, however the document was converted successfully (I can open it in the PDF viewer). Here the code of the function where the error appears. The question now is how to proceed in such a case.

```
################################################################################
#                       Convert attachments to PDF                             #
################################################################################
sub convertAttachments() {
  $logger->info("converting attachments");
  mkdir  $email_converted_attachment_dir;

  opendir(DIR, $email_attachment_dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        $logger->info("Converting attachment: ".$email_attachment_dir.$file);
        $conv_result = "unoconv -v -T 10 -f pdf -o ".$email_converted_attachment_dir." '".$email_attachment_dir.$file."'";
        $logger->info("Running Command: ".$conv_result);
        system($conv_result) and die  "Can't launch unoconv: $!";
    }
  closedir(DIR);
}
```

Comment: Go on. Give us a hint as to what the code's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

man unoconv says:

```
unoconv uses the LibreOffice’s UNO bindings for non-interactive
   conversion of documents and therefore needs an LibreOffice instance to
   communicate with. Therefore if it cannot find one, it will start its
   own instance for temporary usage. If desired, one can start a
   “listener” instance to use for subsequent connections or even for
   remote connections.
```

...

```
-T, --timeout
       When unoconv starts its own listener, try to connect to it for an
       amount of seconds before giving up. Increasing this may help when
       you receive random errors caused by the listener not being ready to
       accept conversion jobs.
```